# Composite Keys on Trigger

Tags: trigger, soql

I want to know the best way to accomplish this task, I have these 3 Objects Suscripcion_Detalle_*c, Direccion*_Entrega__c and Paquete_Detalle__c.

What I need to do is every time there's a new Suscripcion_Detalle__c, is to insert a new Direccion_Entrega__c with the Paquete_Detalle__c values. The thing is that I need to access Paquete_Detalle_*c with a 3 field(Empresa*_c, Paquete_*c, Producto*_c) composite key, it should be something like this:

```
 Trigger SuscripcionDet_CreaDireccionEntrega on Suscripcion_Detalle__c (after insert) {


    Set<Id> idSusDetalle = new Set<Id>();

    List<Direccion_Entrega__c> insertaDe = new List<Direccion_Entrega__c>();

    for(Suscripcion_Detalle__c sd : trigger.new){
        idSusDetalle.add(sd.Id);

    }


    List<Suscripcion_Detalle__c> susDetalles = [SELECT s.Id FROM Suscripcion_Detalle__c s 
                                                WHERE s.Id IN: idSusDetalle];


    for(Suscripcion_Detalle__c sd : susDetalles){


        Direccion_Entrega__c de = new Direccion_Entrega__c(Suscripcion_Detalle_Buscar__c = sd.Id);

                //this is one of the fields I need to fill and should be extracted from Paquete_Detalle__c, I know I can´t use queries inside a for loop, it´s just an example

        de.Cantidad__c = (Cantidad__c FROM Paquete_Detalle__c 
                                 WHERE Empresa__c = de.Empresa__c 
                                 AND  Paquete__c = de.Paquete__c
                                 AND Producto__c = de.Producto__c);

        insertaDe.add(de);
    }


    insert insertaDe;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In above we can skip some lines by doing this way

```
Trigger SuscripcionDet_CreaDireccionEntrega on Suscripcion_Detalle__c (after insert) {
//Set<Id> idSusDetalle = new Set<Id>();
List<Direccion_Entrega__c> insertaDe = new List<Direccion_Entrega__c>();
//for(Suscripcion_Detalle__c sd : trigger.new){
// idSusDetalle.add(sd.Id);
//}
List<Suscripcion_Detalle__c> susDetalles = [SELECT s.Id FROM Suscripcion_Detalle__c s 
                                        WHERE s.Id IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()]
```

writing inside for loop is not good, while trigger running in bulk mode it gives problem, i am not sure about relationships between the three objects, based on proper relationships we can eliminate query inside for loop, one good practise is , writing triggers with helper class, like moving logics to the apex class, invoking apex class from the triggers based on context variables.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply but if you can scroll the code to the right it says the query is not supposed to be there and I already know that, the only thing I want to know is how to retrieve the exact fields that I need

Comment: @Emilio can you get on chat so that I can help you finish the code.http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4337/salesforce

Comment: I found the solution for this, this is the piece of code I used-.                                      for(Suscripcion_Detalle__c sd : susDetalles){
            
            for(Direccion__c dir : direccion){
                
                if(sd.Suscripcion_Buscar__r.Cliente__c == dir.Cliente__c && sd.Id == insertaDe.get(i).Suscripcion_Detalle_Buscar__c){
                
                    insertaDe.get(i).Direccion__c = Dir.Id__c;
                    insertaDe.get(i).Colonia_Buscar__c = Dir.Colonia_Buscar__c;          
                }
            }
            i++;
        }